# External Sorting for large number of block-wise variable length data

Tags: algorithm, sorting, block, mergesort, ram

I need to apply some sorting algorithm on blockwise variable length data. Here are the constraints:

1. Data Length is not fixed.
2. Block Size is fixed.
3. One block contains single/multiple data.
4. Consider I need external sorting. RAM can't hold the whole dataset. Like data set size is 20 GB. Where I can use up to 2GB RAM.

Example:
For simplicity consider each element is space separated word in block.

Consider block size is 26 (including space) and the first block contains 5 element where 2nd block contains only 3 elements.

As blocks are in a fixed size, sorted data may contain more blocks than assorted.

**Blocks:**

[Harry Ron Draco Dark Lord] [Hermione Longbottom Voldemort]

**Sorted Blocks:**

[Dark Draco Harry Hermione] [Lord Longbottom Ron] [Voldemort]

Which algorithm/technique will be efficient for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

My first inclination would be the following:

Write a script that reads the input file, removes the blocks and writes a sequential file. That is, take your file that contains:

```
[Harry Ron Draco Dark Lord] [Hermione Longbottom Voldemort]
```

And write this file:

```
Harry
Ron
Draco
Dark
Lord
Hermione
Longbottom
Voldemort
```

Then, use your system's sort utility (for example GNU `sort`) to sort the file, giving:

```
Dark
Draco
Harry
Hermione
Lord
Longbottom
Ron
Voldemort
```

Then, write a script that reads through that file and constructs the blocks, writing them to the final output.

This almost certainly is not the most efficient in terms of running time, but it's simple, reliable, easy to code, and easy to prove correct. You can probably code it up and test with a subset of the data in an hour or two. Then set it to work on the entire data set.

Comment: Removing the blocking would be removing one of the constraints in the question.

Comment: @rcgldr How so? You're going to add it back once you've sorted the data. Look at the OP's examples. The result he gets is exactly the result you'd get if you followed my procedure.

Comment: My assumption about the block size constraint is that all I/O has to be a multiple (one or more) of the block size during the sort, not just before and after the sort, even though the end result is the same. I'm also wondering about scripting in Windows and if it could deblock the data.

Comment: @rcgldr If your assumptions about the I/O hold, then obviously my approach won't work so well. Scripting in Windows? Shouldn't be a problem, although it's been a few years since I worked with Windows much: things could have changed. But a few years back I could write scripts in VBScript, JavaScript, Powershell (ugh), or ... heck, whatever language.

Comment: @rcgldr I think the example of words in 26-character blocks was a proxy for the real problem. Hard to say. But the concepts should work, regardless.

Comment: I deleted my most recent comment (about how variable length data is stored). I'll delete this comment later.

Comment: @JimMischel  We need to read data in blocks and write the data in blocks. In between during computation, we can interchange the element of blocks or even eliminate the block as you Said. But due to memory constraint, it is not possible to read as many as blocks at a time. After reading couple of blocks it is must to spill the data from memory, i.e. to write it back to file(of course in blocks :) ).

Comment: @MubashwirAlam You need to fully specify the constraints in your question. How do you expect us to provide a useful answer if we don't know all of the rules?

Comment: @JimMischel, I am sorry. My mistake. But I thought constraint # 4 implies my last comment.

Comment: @MubashwirAlam My algorithm does not use very much memory. The first step reads the file one block at a time, de-blocks it, and writes to output. The sorting step uses the system-supplied sort utility, which knows how to sort a file that's larger than available memory. The last step reads the sorted file line-by-line until it can fill a block, outputs the block, and repeats. Nothing in this solution will use more than the 2GB of memory.

Answer (score 1):

An external merge sort will work. The statement "sorted data may contain more blocks than assorted" implies data records don't span blocks, so the number of blocks may vary due to unused space in blocks during the sort and merge process. The first pass reads a set of blocks into memory, sorts the data records, then writes a sorted run of blocks to a file, repeating this process until all of the original data is processed. The remaining passes merge the files, until a single sorted file is produced. A k-way merge can be used for this process, with 2-way being the simplest. For k > 2, a minheap would help in finding which of k runs has the "smallest" next element. To reduce I/O overhead, read and write multiple blocks at a time.